# Which sub-chunks should I support in my wav audio decoder program?

Tags: c#, audio, .net-core

I am writing my own music player, starting with the wav file format. I'm able to play and seek wav files, and now I'm wondering which of the sub-chunks I should try to parse or which I should skip over. The `fmt` and `data` chunks are obviously necessary, and I assume `INFO` is pertinent too. Are there any other sub-chunks that I shouldn't be skipping over?

Comment: Did you read the WIKI article?.  The name of the music (INFO) and silent chunks are not important in listening to music.   Only the wav data and format is necessary to listen to the music.  See : https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/WAV

Comment: I have read the article, I know that those chunks are the only ones important for listening to the music. Perhaps I could have worded my question in a better way. I'm curious which chunks have information inside them that will be worthwhile to the average user.

Comment: Unfortunately that is a question that will be "primarily opinion-based". Something that is "important" to me might not be important to you. Certainly, if you skip the chunks that contain data that make the sound output on my end, that's going to be important to us both, but other than that, you need to decide yourself.

Comment: This link is  better (http://soundfile.sapp.org/doc/WaveFormat/).  I'm not sure what you are looking for pertaining to a WAV format.

Comment: It does seem like a "primarily opinion-based" thing to me too, but I thought perhaps there are sub-chunks besides the format and data chunk that most music players out there read and use or present to the user. Which is why I decided to ask this question.